# Traversing to the first value in a list in Jquery Autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm trying to refer to the value in a list using jQuery to traverse through the divs to get the value.

I have tried so many different ways including .get(), .find() and .children().

I'm using jQuery autocomplete plugin so I can't add the code here! However I have a screenshot attached.

Note: I believe that I need to refer to the `ui-menu-item-wrapper` something like `ui-menu-item-wrapper[0]` rather than the `ui-id-2` or `tabindex`.

How do I get the value in the of the first item in the list?

[image]

Edit: Figured out how to copy the code!

```
<ul id="ui-id-1" tabindex="0" class="ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-autocomplete ui-front" style="display: none; width: 746px; position: relative; top: -2465.55px; left: 261.858px;" xpath="1">
   <li class="ui-menu-item">
      <div id="ui-id-2" tabindex="-1" class="ui-menu-item-wrapper">French</div>
   </li>
   <li class="ui-menu-item">
      <div id="ui-id-3" tabindex="-1" class="ui-menu-item-wrapper">Mayfair</div>
   </li>
   <li class="ui-menu-item">
      <div id="ui-id-4" tabindex="-1" class="ui-menu-item-wrapper">Fish in a Tie</div>
   </li>
   <li class="ui-menu-item">
      <div id="ui-id-5" tabindex="-1" class="ui-menu-item-wrapper">French Cuisine</div>
   </li>
   <li class="ui-menu-item">
      <div id="ui-id-6" tabindex="-1" class="ui-menu-item-wrapper">Fine Dining</div>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: None of the values you put in `gray` are valid selectors.  http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/selecting-elements/  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors

Comment: Please post the actual code you are using and a representative sample of the HTML - preferably in a snippet running jQuery (use CTRL-M in the editor)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: " I can't add the code here" - sure you can...

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss Sorry! Just figured out how to copy it from chrome dev tools!

Comment: how do you propose to know which item you are after?  do you know the `id`, text, or index of the item you are looking for?

Comment: I saw that I could use .get() to get the first line, but cant figure out how to use it!
https://api.jquery.com/get/

Comment: What are you really trying to do/how are you using that?

Comment: @James5949 the Autocomplete list is only opened when a user has entered some text in the field. When the user makes a selection, the value of the field is updated. So you can collect the value after the user has made a selection. It feels like you have something more that you want to do yet have not revealed it in the Post. Please expand on your question or see the answer from Mark that has already been posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to answer directly, the menu items get created and destroyed often, so you have to get the first one when it has some.  The menu item is created when the autocomplete is created, but the items inside are what changes.

SO, given that, we can find them in an event for instance the "open" event so we can then select the first one from that.  Here, I show the text of the first item in the menu in a `console.log(di)`

```js
$(function() {
  var mythings = ["c++", "java", "php", "coldfusion", "javascript", "asp", "ruby"];
  var myA = $("#myautomagicautocomplete");
  myA.autocomplete({
    autoFocus: true,
    source: mythings
  });
  var w = myA.autocomplete("widget");
  myA.on("autocompleteopen", function(event, ui) {
      // var w = myA.autocomplete("widget");
      var fi = w.find('.ui-menu-item').first();
      var di = fi.find('.ui-menu-item-wrapper').text();
      console.dir(di);
    });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.theme.min.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="myautomagicautocomplete" />
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I spent 3 hours trying to figure this out!

Answer (score 0):

Find the element with a class of `.ui-menu-item-wrapper` that is a child of a `li` with the class of `.ui-menu-item`.

```
$(li.ui-menu-item .ui-menu-item-wrapper')
```

Comment: Were you thinking something like this: $('li.ui-menu-item .ui-menu-item-wrapper').val() ? I've tried this way... and tried it again with no success! I need to somehow refer to it like [1] or something i think!

Answer (score 0):

A `div` in html doesn't generally have a value, I am going to assume you know the text [or part of it] that you are searching for.

I have provided 3 examples in the snippet below;

1. The first is getting the menu item by `ui-id`
2. The second is getting the menu item by a subset of the content.
3. Always get the `nth` menu item **note that the first index is 1 as opposed to zero**

```js
// if you know the ui-id number
var idNum = 6;
//console.log(`#ui-id-${idNum}`);
console.log($(`#ui-id-${idNum}`).text());
// if you know some of the content
var txt = "Fish";
//console.log(`div.ui-menu-item-wrapper:contains(${txt})`);
console.log($(`div.ui-menu-item-wrapper:contains(${txt})`).text());
//always get the nth menu-item
var index = 1;
console.log($(`.ui-menu-item:nth-child(${index}) > div.ui-menu-item-wrapper`).text());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="ui-id-1" tabindex="0" class="ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-autocomplete ui-front" style="display: block; width: 746px; position: relative; top: -2465.55px; left: 261.858px;" xpath="1">
  <li class="ui-menu-item">
    <div id="ui-id-2" tabindex="-1" class="ui-menu-item-wrapper">French</div>
  </li>
  <li class="ui-menu-item">
    <div id="ui-id-3" tabindex="-1" class="ui-menu-item-wrapper">Mayfair</div>
  </li>
  <li class="ui-menu-item">
    <div id="ui-id-4" tabindex="-1" class="ui-menu-item-wrapper">Fish in a Tie</div>
  </li>
  <li class="ui-menu-item">
    <div id="ui-id-5" tabindex="-1" class="ui-menu-item-wrapper">French Cuisine</div>
  </li>
  <li class="ui-menu-item">
    <div id="ui-id-6" tabindex="-1" class="ui-menu-item-wrapper">Fine Dining</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```